# symfony4.3 adding custom folder with classes

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

In my default symfony4 structure I want to add **lib** folder, where I have additional classes. So something like this:

```
-bin
-config
-lib
  - Importer.php
  ...(other files with classes)
-public
-src
   - Controller
      - TestController.php
   - Entity
   - Form
  ...
...
```

But I cannot figure out how to later use my files (i.e.: Importer.php).

Let's say Importer.php has a single **class Importer()** inside. If I try to use it from TestController.php I get:

> Attempted to load class "Importer" from namespace "lib". Did you
>   forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

TestController.php has

```
use Importer;
```

specified on top (autodetected by PhpStorm). I also tried adding namespace in my Importer.php file, for example:

```
namespace lib;
```

and then in TestController:

```
use lib\Importer;
```

But it produces the same result.

Lastly after reading about services, I tried adding the file to config/services.yaml

```
lib\:
    resource: '../lib/Importer.php'
```

Which gives the same result...

What to do, how to live?

Comment: You will need to update your composer.json file to allow the autoloader to find you new files.  And you probably will want to spend some time learning about namespaces and how to use them.

Comment: @Cerad on my list of things to learn...

Comment: Out of curiosity: what's the need for adding a seperate folder on the root level? Why not use it as the best practises suggest? Is that some kind of common dependency, also needed for other projects?

Comment: @Nick it is indeed common dependency, which apart from being used by the app, is also being used directly by cron on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all read about [php namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Next read about the [psr-4 standart](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

Select a prefix for your folder, let's say `Lib`. Make sure that all files in the `lib` folder has a properly namespace. E.g. `Importer` class must be stored in the `lib\Importer.php` and must have the `namespace Lib;`, `Items\Item` class must be stored in the `lib\Items\Item.php` and must have the `namespace Lib\Items\Item;` and so on.

Your files are ready. Just need to inform Symfony about them.

Symfony uses composer's autoloader, so check [composer's autoload section](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading). Than add new folder for autoloading in `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "Lib\\": "lib/"
    }
},
```

It says that all classes in `lib` folder have their own separate files and `Lib` prefix in their namespace and other part of namespace is similar to directories structure.

Next you need to clear autoloader's cache. Run in console:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

And finally you can use your class:

```
use Lib\Importer;

$importer = new Importer;
```

Also you can add your files to [autowire](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#the-autowire-option).